# How can I use android intent with an expo app

Tags: android, expo

How can I use android-intent with expo (like this for example:)

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
   .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/your.apk"), 
                   "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `IntentLauncher` api: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/intent-launcher/

Comment: I tried that but it gives me an error(Intent is not a constructor ) so I don't know how to specify a path or how to open a specific app and not use the given Intent options.